# How to add userChrome.js and config-prefs.js to firefox snap

Tags: firefox, snap, firefox-extensions

I'm tyring to follow this guide on github
https://github.com/tsaost/autoload-temporary-addon

I'm trying to add the files as described in that repo.

Their are two files that need to be added.

`config-prefs.js`

`userChrome.js`

so I tried adding

`/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/config-prefs.js`

and

`/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/userChrome.js`

With the command

`cp /tmp/config-prefs.js /snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/config-prefs.js`

but it says its a read only filesystem

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/config-prefs.js': Read-only file system
```

So I have 3 questions.

1. Is this the correct place to add these files, or should they be added to
   `~/snap/firefox/current/`?
   its worth noting that that directory seems to be mostly empty.
2. If the root snap dir `/snap/` is the right place how do I resolve the read only file system error?
3. If it should go into profile snap dir `~/snap/` should I just create the necessary sub-directory's `usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/` to add the files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.

Comment: AFAIK, snaps were designed to give the snap developer control of his/her environtment, and disallow local alterations. See https://ubuntu.com/core/services/guide/snaps-intro

Comment: Well the guide doesn't really specify steps Cleary because it's for windows. The only thing I've tried is todo a `cp` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 10+ hours of googling I've figured it out.
The files should be added as

`/etc/firefox/userChrome.js`

`/etc/firefox/defaults/pref/config-prefs.js`

create the directorys if they do not exist.
although `/etc/firefox` should already be there

if you are running firefox version 117+ you will also need to remove the statement that spans lines `99-100` from `userChrome.js`.

This is the statement that needs to be removed.

```
const {Services} = Components.utils.
                         import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
```